# Android GLSL fragment shader on NVIDIA tegra2

Tags: android, tegra

I'm developing an app for the android galaxy tab 10.1 which has the Tegra 250 T20. I am writing a shader in GLSL that has a for() loop. I want the for() loop to terminate early under some conditions.

What I'm seeing is that the shader compiler has unwound the loop and the entire unwound code is being executed, which kills the performance.

Here's the question: Does the Tegra 250 T20 support the execution flow instructions at all? And if so, how can I tell the compiler to actually make use of them.

Thanks very much for any and all replies.

ETA: glGetString(GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) returns "OpenGL ES GLSL 1.00".

Also if the GLSL can't handle it, how can I write in the ARB assembly language to do it myself?

ETA2: GL_EXTENSIONS has this:
GL_NV_platform_binary
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_NV_depth_nonlinear
GL_NV_draw_path
GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_NV_framebuffer_vertex_attrib_array
GL_NV_coverage_sample
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_ARB_draw_buffers
GL_EXT_Cg_shader
GL_EXT_packed_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_EXT_texture_array
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_NV_get_tex_image
GL_NV_read_buffer
GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_EXT_bgra
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update

Answer (score 1):

On most embedded Platforms - I believe all plattforms that only support version 120 - GLSL does not support any kind of dynamic looping. For example: You can't declare a variable to determine how often the loop should loop.

The only possibility is to split it up in several conditional blocks, if applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The glGetString(GLES20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) does return this:OpenGL ES GLSL 1.00.

Comment: Yes: so you seem to be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Neigher the Tegra vertex nor fragment shader units supports dynamic control-flow; you need loops to be possible to unroll at compile time. Most other OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations supports dynamic control-flow, but the standard does not require it.